# How to map a Servlet to get extra path information with getPathInfo()

Tags: java, tomcat, rest, servlets

I am having an issue where Tomcat is treating extra path information as part of the servlet name.  This is breaking a bunch of RESTFul functionality in our webapp (we use extra path info rather than ?name=value pairs for crawler friendly links).

It was working correctly before, but it broke after adding explicit mappings and removing the `Invoker` servlet that we previously used to serve our servlets.  For example consider the following link:

> http://mydomain.com/servlet/MyServlet/param1/param2/param3

`MyServlet` used to be called correctly, and "/param1/param2/param3" was returned by `getPathInfo()` on the `HttpServletRequest`.

Now, it appears that Tomcat is trying to load MyServlet/param1/param2/param3 as the servlet:

> [23/Sep/2008:16:44:23 -0700] "GET
>   /servlet/MyServlet/param1/param2/param3
>   HTTP/1.0" 404

Here is the way they are defined and mapped in the web.xml, and just hitting
"http://mydomain.com/servlet/MyServlet" works fine.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.myclass.etcetera.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map it to /servlet/MyServlet/*

You are missing the trailing "/*".